# Is it hypothetically possible to splice layers of separate docker images?

Tags: docker

I'm curious to understand a little more about the anatomy of docker images.  I understand how this works in context of `docker build`:  each step in the build file creates a new layer building on the last and that both `FROM` clauses and layer caching can mean layers are re-used between images.

I also know that layers are effectively composited using [overlayfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS) or similar with changes causing edited / new / deleted files to have whole files or blackout files stored in each layer.

What I don't know is how these layers are then bound together.  I don't know if there is a back reference in each layer to its parent, or if the sequencing of layers is defined by metadata held separately.

**What I'm particularly curious about is whether or not it is **hypothetically** possible to take layers from unrelated images and splice them together into a new (working) image?**.  That is splice them without creating and storing copies in the docker repo.  You may assume that the unrelated images were constructed for this purpose.

---

*Note: this is not an XY question. I genuinely want to know the answer to this question as asked... because I want to know*

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the question: what do you mean by "what I don't know is how these layers are bound together"? As you've already noted, the layers are composited using overlayfs, which effectively takes a list of separate directories and merges them together. You could happily composite layers from different images by manually running the appropriate `mount` command (although the result might not necessarily be functional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change layers of an image independently from each other. References to each of the layers are stored in a list in the image manifest, and there is no block chain like reference between the layers. However the manifest, and the references to each of the layers inside of that manifest, are each referenced by a digest which is a hash of the content, which makes it effectively a Merkle tree. You can't change any of the content within the image without changing the digest of that manifest.

There are various tools out there that let you "rebase" a container image, typically used to change the version of the base image. The best known tool for this is [buildpacks](https://buildpacks.io/). In addition to rebasing images, there are also tools out there that allow you to modify or mutate images. This is typically packaged as a tool rather than modifying the JSON/tar file directly, because you need to manage references to the digest.

If you add/remove/modify a layer in an image, there are three places that need to be updated:

1. The image manifest layers descriptor. This points to the digest of the blob in the registry, typically that's a compressed tar (tgz).
2. The image config rootfs list. This is the digest of the uncompressed layer tar file.
3. The image config history, which contains an entry with empty_layer undefined or set to false for each image layer.

OCI has the [image manifest](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/manifest.md) and [image config](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/config.md) specs in their GitHub repo. Because the registry typically stores the blobs compressed, the digest will be different from the rootfs for the same content.

The docker "parent" field is docker specific, not part of OCI. You can certainly pull an OCI image into docker, or an image with the docker media types but using OCI content in the config (the format is the same with a few less fields). And docker doesn't even look at those files when loading an image:

```
$ ls */json
0676900a3fcaf27be5f22845f16bd5d58d9269dc3de03306acac995d56035efa/json
3344a9101a1ca321da60b65254dbb66a7cbbdf151a60ed0fab07b79c20ffcbf8/json
59b9a89a0561acd5d2db5f96a7c9d989dc3d504be9616c3361d991ce0530143a/json
705e6be633f9c28e022b58592f13b2bfd8d63303f65b34811593614336980b43/json
94487aa19b3e2ea52ddf64b20804b05321b473c9aa27604518ae936ed8bd3672/json

$ rm */json

$ tar -cf - . | docker load
Loaded image: somerepo:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

> Docker has to know the order to compose them into a container. something knows what order the layers go in.

Right, that information is provided by the [image manifest](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/manifest.md), which is a JSON file that, among other information, contains an ordered list of layers.

For example, let's look at the official `postgres:15` image. We can grab the contents for inspection like this:

```
mkdir postgres-image
docker image save postgres:15 | tar -C postgres-image -xf-
```

Which gets us:

```
$ ls postgres-image
1c035120f97a959821c3d682e5ddb1b826410b01f1a66ef71426085d11abbac2
1cde06c3f46bf13f0d87eeacc400abc4b80283952c96a0f586a3c4dbc53dea8d
4c6b3cc10e6bbb2afd68caa44a3eb6cef12caf483e60b28c6de2c56e8f1b99bc.json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.json
repositories
```

The manifest is contained in `manifest.json`, which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Config": "4c6b3cc10e6bbb2afd68caa44a3eb6cef12caf483e60b28c6de2c56e8f1b99bc.json",
    "RepoTags": [
      "postgres:15"
    ],
    "Layers": [
      "fc5484c1b2ce93576cc100282c8e446581c5ffd48e6199a8b2d651d7f9171124/layer.tar",
      "d10e11a29048914235b611ff7a0c93ebb529b1d1f8f0e00f883a341f0193d9ab/layer.tar",
      "a2036affeb348540e00efc39a5bc8e8f099327725b0e81ce068c4e55ac76cb50/layer.tar",
      "1cde06c3f46bf13f0d87eeacc400abc4b80283952c96a0f586a3c4dbc53dea8d/layer.tar",
      "7de3bcc2590b6a6bdf63c49e4861b2d44234de5aff1017c982b51ae8343a8f9d/layer.tar",
      "aea69f9cbe92ef8c8efd388c69e169f036070c8ab068acf993cf9096010e4191/layer.tar",
      "586bebe8d837fb5b377b572f83f88d65c3c667624edf6230951a4a714c2d879b/layer.tar",
      "9ec9c81974bf829a515052eb4a318630bcaf43abd02bf4e59703f796fc5df66d/layer.tar",
      "1c035120f97a959821c3d682e5ddb1b826410b01f1a66ef71426085d11abbac2/layer.tar",
      "e72ed9131fa5b904acf7bcfe7978f97e99c9fb087308b7cefd5063edea0bf7b8/layer.tar",
      "eaf7c4940ac93309a059cc3f91f847a130317a98c7380e0534b2c525c8e805a3/layer.tar",
      "d24fc4b0912a24f160d52cf9273bf07f0ca18ed0ae1855e41e4c1cbefa650dd5/layer.tar",
      "866914886a5c213ca953042f6d9f15a2a803ef8318321651f45552aff0910d9b/layer.tar"
    ]
  }
]
```

That list of layers is how Docker knows how to compose the final image: you start with the first layer, and then apply each subsequent layer on top of it.

> I don't know if there is a back reference in each layer to its parent, or if the sequencing of layers is defined by metadata held separately.

The answer is "both". The sequencing is defined by the list of layers in the manifest, but each layer also contains a reference to its parent. For example, if we look at the file `1cde06c3f46bf13f0d87eeacc400abc4b80283952c96a0f586a3c4dbc53dea8d/json`, we see:

```
{
  "id": "1cde06c3f46bf13f0d87eeacc400abc4b80283952c96a0f586a3c4dbc53dea8d",
  "parent": "a2036affeb348540e00efc39a5bc8e8f099327725b0e81ce068c4e55ac76cb50",
  "created": "1969-12-31T19:00:00-05:00",
  "container_config": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": null,
    "Cmd": null,
    "Image": "",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": null
  },
  "os": "linux"
}
```

The attribute `parent` is a reference to the previous layer.

Comment: Well, like I said, you could manually splice them together with the appropriate `mount` command. You could manipulate the storage in `/var/lib/docker` to create a fake image that consists of layers from multiple distinct images. There are several ways to do what you've asked, although again the chances are you'd end up with a collection of files that wouldn't necessarily be functional.

Comment: Sure it would! You'd get something you could run using `docker run` on your local system, which at least meets my definition of an image. You could also obviously build a new image by constructing the necessary directory structure (and `manifest.json`), and then tarring it up and feeding it to `docker image load`.

Comment: If you create a new image in your local docker daemon, you can then `docker push` that somewhere else. Ta da! And the other option -- manually constructing an image by creating the appropriate directory structure and then bundling it up with tar -- doesn't require hacking anything. To be clear, I don't think these are *practical* options, but there's nothing to stop you from splicing together random layers, which was your original question.